# computing function of neighbors efficiently on lattice

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, data-structures, nearest-neighbor

I'm studying the [Ising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) model, and I'm trying to efficiently compute a function `H(`σ`)` where σ is the current state of an `L`x`L` lattice (that is, σ_ij ∈ `{+1, -1}` for `i,j` ∈ `{1,2,...,L}`). To compute `H` for a particular σ, I need to perform the following calculation:

[image]

where ⟨i j⟩ indicates that sites σ_i and σ_j are nearest neighbors and (suppose) J is a constant.

A couple of questions:

1. Should I store my state σ as an `L`x`L` matrix or as an `L`<sup>2</sup> list? Is one better than the other for memory accessing in RAM (which I guess depends on the way I'm accessing elements...)?
2. In either case, how can I best compute `H`?

Really I think this boils down to how can I access (and manipulate) the neighbors of every state most efficiently.

Some thoughts:

1. I see that if I loop through each element in the list or matrix that I'll be double counting, so is there a "best" way to return the unique neighbors?
2. Is there a better data structure that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad and a bit confusing for me, so excuse me if my answer is not the one you are looking for, but I hope it will help (a bit).

---

An array is faster than a list when it comes to indexing. A matrix is a 2D array, like this for example (where `N` and `M` are both `L` for you):

[image]

That means that you first access `a[i]` and then `a[i][j]`.

However, you can avoid this double access, by emulating a 2D array with a 1D array. In that case, if you want to access element `a[i][j]` in your matrix, you would now do, `a[i * L + j]`.

That way you load once, but you multiply and add your variables, but this may still be faster in *some cases*.

---

Now as for the Nearest Neighbor question, it seems that you are using a [square-lattice Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-lattice_Ising_model), which means that you are working in 2 dimensions.

A very efficient data structure for Nearest Neighbor Search in low dimensions is the [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). The construction of that tree takes `O(nlogn)`, where `n` is the size of your dataset.

Now *you* should think if it's worth it to build such a data structure.

PS: There is a plethora of libraries implementing the kd-tree, such as CGAL.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem during one of my school assignments and I think the solution depends on which programming language you are using.

In terms of efficiency, there is no better way than to write a for loop to sum neighbours(which are actually the set of 4 points{ (i+/-1,j+/-1)} for a given (i,j). However, when simd(sse etc) functions are available, you can re-express this as a convolution with a 2d  kernel {0 1 0;1 0 1;0 1 0}. so if you use a numerical library which exploits simd functions you can obtain significant performance increase. You can see the example implementation of this here(https://github.com/zawlin/cs5340/blob/master/a1_code/denoiseIsingGibbs.py) .
Note that in this case, the performance improvement is huge because to evaluate it in python I need to write an expensive for loop.

In terms of work, there is in fact some waste as the unecessary multiplications and sum with zeros at corners and centers. So whether you can experience performance improvement depends quite a bit on your programming environment( if you are already in c/c++, it can be difficult and you need to use mkl etc to obtain good improvement)